# Array of Variants in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, variants

In c#, I want declare a function with a Dinamic array that receive any type of data primitive types like (string, integer, doubles, datetimes ....) but this types are not a Object , just a basic types.
There is someway to do this ?

Comment: string is not primitive. string is an object. Also, considering the fact that all structs, classes inherit Object class whether that's implicitly or explicitly, yes it's possible by using the object type as the parameter. Also, you might what to look at object type params array.

Comment: Little bit unclear, anyway did you consider ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works, but Have a Limitation, he don't works with diferentes types of data like a

`MyFunc(new[] {"alpha", 123, 01-02-2002});`

This code below works with string, int and date

```
public bool ArrayVariant(string pQuery, ICollection collection)
{

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
             //do something with item
        }
}
```

and to call function

```
ArrayVariant( "any data", new dynamic[]  {"teste", 0, DateTime.Now});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public static void MyFunc(params object[] items)
{
    foreach (object item in items)
        // Do somthing with item
}
```

Call it like

```
MyFunc("test", 0, DateTime.Now);
```